# run app from terminal error with rstudioapi::selectDirectory

Tags: shiny

I want to launch a shiny application from a terminal. My application has a button that when pressed opens a window to select a folder with the function **rstudioapi::selectDirectory()**

But when i click on the button i get this error:

```
Warning: Error in : RStudio not running
  76: stop
  75: verifyAvailable
  74: callFun
  73: rstudioapi::selectDirectory
  72: observeEventHandler [D:/Users/folder/Shiny/app.R#12]
   1: shiny::runApp
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  actionButton("folder", "Choose folder")

)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$folder, {
    path.file <- rstudioapi::selectDirectory()
    print(path.file)
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**on a terminal**

```
$ "Rscript.exe" -e "shiny::runApp('Shiny/app.R')"
Loading required package: shiny
Warning: package 'shiny' was built under R version 3.5.3

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6283
Warning: Error in : RStudio not running
  76: stop
  75: verifyAvailable
  74: callFun
  73: rstudioapi::selectDirectory
  72: observeEventHandler [D:/Users/folder/Shiny/app.R#12]
   1: shiny::runApp
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running in a Shiny process, not RStudio.